# Does the HSK6 exam paper H61218 question 54 (语病) have a correct answer?

Tags: grammar

This is a HSK6 语病 question, wherein precisely one sentence is ungrammatical in some way:

> 1. 昨天我从火车站出来的时候,天下了大雨。
> 2. 鲸的体形像鱼,但却是用肺呼吸、胎生的哺乳动物。
> 3. 伤害人的话语就像泼出去的水,一旦说出就永远无法收回。
> 4. 有个成语叫“熟能生巧”,这里的“巧”其实就是不断重复练习的结果。
>
> <sub>HSK6 H61218 Q.54</sub>

The [given answer](https://archive.org/details/elsey_HSK6) is 1, but three native speakers [here](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/10795686) and [here](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/18788781) didn't find any major issues with it; one wrote: 前句无介词（我不确定，严格说来要介词）.  This makes me wonder if any of these sentences are ungrammatical.  I don't see any errors myself.

**Question**: Does the HSK6 exam paper H61218 question 54 (语病) have a correct answer?

(PS. For precedent, the correct answer to H61008 Q.53 is B, but the official answer is C.  So the answers are not infallible.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with the aspect.

昨天我从火车站出来的时候 is a point of time, while 了 is a dynamic perfect particle. According to the context, the sentence is meant to say that it *was raining* when I got out of the train station yesterday. Thus 下了 should be changed to 下着 or 正在下.

It's wrong to say 严格说来要介词. At the sentence-initial position, the temporal phrase uses the unmarked form, i.e. a bare NP. Note that the unmarked temporal phrase should be thought as a separate form of temporal phrases, not as ellipsis of the coverb.

Answer (score 4):

了 indicated completeness of the verb

昨天我从火车站出来的时候,天下了大雨。 Would mean the rain has stopped. It is incompatible with 的时候 (the time/ moment)

It should be 昨天我从火车站出来的时候,天(正)下**著**大雨。(It was raining at that moment) or 昨天我从火车站出来的时候,天下(起)了大雨。(it started raining at that moment)

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer should be 2, instead of 1.

> 鲸的体形像鱼,但却是用肺呼吸、胎生的哺乳动物。

The topic is 鲸, not 鲸的体形. So, it should be something like:

> 鲸, (它的)体形像鱼,但却是用肺呼吸、胎生的哺乳动物。

Basically, it mixed up the subjects of 鲸 and 鲸的体形. It might be okay in spoken, but not in the formal writing.

Comment: That is a good point!  Many other answers follow the this logic, such as 7月的内蒙古**草原**,是一个美丽的**季节** and **中国**是扇子的故乡,**在中国**有着悠久的历史.

Comment: It is just a simple case of omitting the  subject 鲸的体形像鱼,但(它)却是用肺呼吸、胎生的哺乳动物。

Comment: similarly,  車沒有腳，但(車)卻被稱為代步工具 -->車沒有腳，但(它)卻被稱為代步工具 -->  車沒有腳，但(subject is 車)卻被稱為代步工具

Comment: @TangHo Well, your sentence "車沒有腳，但(車)卻被稱為代步工具" is different from "鲸的体形像鱼,但却是用肺呼吸、胎生的哺乳动物。", where additional 的 makes it wrong. If it wrote 鲸体形像鱼,但却是用肺呼吸、胎生的哺乳动物, then it would be acceptable.